# Regular expression for matching a key:value pair

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regular expression in PHP for matching a **key:value** pair, where **key** is a word and **value** is a positive float number:

```
preg_match('/^(\w+):(?!0\d)\d*(\.\d+)?/i', $string, $match);
```

If I input a string such as:

**Europe:6**

```
print_r($match)
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Europe:6 [1] => Europe )
```

Omitting the **value** part.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around the value.

Comment: Looks like this could be causing your issues `(?!0\d)`. Your input string doesn't look like it's matched by that, so it's not catching the part of the value you have in the ()'s. I can't tell, but are you trying to match numbers where a decimal might be present? A better solution might be to replace `(?!0\d)\d*(\.\d+)?` with `([-\.\d]+)`. Just a thought.

Comment: your regular expression is perfect work. show here your $string value.

Comment: The regex is 'perfect' by what standard? It doesn't match what he wants. His string value is shown in the post as `Europe:6` as an example.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to match positive numbers where a decimal might be present or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to capture a value that is a positive floating point paired with some key, I would suggest you try this instead:

```
preg_match('/^(\w+):([\.\d]+)/i', $string, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(\w+)=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)
```

Group 1 will contain key, while Group 2 will contain the value.

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BAL0x1)**</kbd>

#### PHP

```
<?php
$string = "europe:6";
preg_match('/^(\w+):(?!0\d)(\d*)?/i', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

#### Output

```
Array ( [0] => europe:6 [1] => europe [2] => 6 )
```

Here i test and modify your <kbd>**[Regular Expression](http://regex101.com/r/zV8iL6)**</kbd>

Hope this help you!